# Reuse components with internal state an vuex module store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to reuse a Counter component with his own internal store.

The problem is when I change the state, it´s changed in all the Counter instances. I´m returning state as `state = () => ({})` but, It´s shared in all instances...

How can setup this to use his own state?
Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-black-k9e8f

Comment: Vuex is used for sharing state. If you want the component to have its own state, then declare the state in that component, or you can achieve what you want by passing props to the component.

Comment: This is only an example. I need mutations to track the changes, so If I don´t use modules, If I have for example 100 differents components with multiple instances of each, I need to write all the actions, mutations for the 100 components in the store.js. Can I use Vuex writing all the muttions/actions/getter in the component?

Comment: Could you please be more clear in your requirement?.... I can see your counter component is created multiple times. But everyone is subscribed to same store instance, so all will show same value. Thats how store works

Comment: I need each Counter instance has his own state and not everyone use the same instance. Imagine that Counter component has a button to multiply by 2 the internal value of that component instance. I want only mutate that instance and not all the instances. I updated the demo to add the multiply button example. Thanks!

Comment: I´m totally beginner, so maybe I'm confusing concepts, but I can't mix data and computed properties with actions and mutations in the same component, right? I think that using actions and mutations requires a `state` and I would like to separate it by modules. Maybe I need [dynamic module registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration)?? But how??